# URL Patterns to exclude in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, url-pattern

How many URL patterns can exclude at a time in a test case using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Recently what I learned is that, We can create numerous URL patterns to exclude in 
JMeter.